# Preventing a bottleneck in devicecommunication

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance

I've got quite an abstract question. I'm working on a project that requires constant device communication. I'm integrating multiple devices onto an external processing unit with a touchpanel to execute certain methods. I.e. the "start videocall" button on the touchpanel activates a relay, turns a display-device, camera-device and microphone-device on, etc.

On the flipside, I'm also trying to monitor these devices. What status do they currently have? Are they enabled/disabled ? What input is the display device currently on?

So far, I've come up with two solutions to prevent a bottleneck in the communication where I'm constantly polling (i.e. every two to five seconds to keep an acurate and up-to-date status) the on-state and input-state of the display-device.

1. Make use of threading so I can enqueue the different commands and execute them async. By also reading the response async, all communication should be nicely spaced out but I'd have a very "busy" communication line, taking it's toll on the processing unit.
2. With the help of events have the display-device notify the processor of it's changed status. This would take a lot of stress off of the communication line, but I feel like this is very easily disrupted. If the device doesn't throw it's events correctly (or the events are missed out on) the monitored state does not correspond with the actual state.

I'm curious if there are other ways of going about this issue. As of now, I'm leaning towards the second one because it stresses the processing unit a whole lot less, I just feel like I should be building in a lot of safeguards to prevent an inacurate representation of the actual device-states.

The project runs in C# on .Net 3.5.

Comment: Hi, in general and most abstract form, events are not guaranteed to be delivered. On the other hand; I never have encountered a non-delivered event which wasn't due to my own lack of programming skills. So, option 2 would be the "better" way, unless ofcourse you encounter problems. Btw: sometimes you can correct for these states by implementing functionality. E.g.: a back button to restore the state, check the current state before transitioning to the next, a timeout mechanism. A final tip: try to implement a `statemachine` to prevent excessive `if/else` wiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling works, but it isn't fun or optimal.  Reactive is best but as you've mentioned there may be a hiccup insuring your still listening to to the device and not just standing by for nothing.  In this situation it makes since to optimize both processes.  Poll when you're waiting or haven't heard a response in so long and listen when your polling returns good info, passing the polling.

That said, you shouldn't worry about taxing the unit too much with polling on various threads. This sounds like a purpose device so as long as you're not running it hot or stressing it to max all the time then using your resources are perfectly fine.

Comment: So basically try and combine both implementations? Whenever an event hasn't been triggered for an hour, I'll poll once and if the active state quals the monitored state, I'll poll again in an hour if the event hasn't been triggered yet ?  
That honeslty sounds like a solid implementation. As @Stefan already implied, the reason I'm kind of doubtfull to rely on events is because I'm not confident in my own programming skills.

Comment: @Ciphra Well, don't doubt yourself or your skills.  If you make a mistake, learn what went wrong and fix it. But unless you have a way of knowing that the device is still connected then a mixture of both would work. You basically need a heartbeat of some kind, either built in or engineered on your own, to tell you the device is there.  Then you just need to manage the state of the device accurately.  There's no perfect solution.

Comment: Most devices are connected with a TCPClient which has an event that triggeres when the connectionstate changes. This could function as the heartbeat you mentioned. Still I'm leaning towards the combined implementation of polling and listening.

Comment: @Ciphra You're correct, the TCP has it built in, which is what I was referring to.  What device / OS is initializing the TCP?

Comment: it's a serverlike device commonly refered to (on the workfloor here) as a processor. It starts the program/system and keeps it running unless it breaks because of bad code or you tell it to stop. The programs/systems designed are mostly just integrating multiple devices to be controlled from a single controlpanel, usually touchpanels but possibly analog controlpanels as well. I'm fairly certain they run a self-written OS in it as well.